# ASIC timing constraints via SDC: How to correctly specify a multiplexed clock?

Tags: clock, timing, constraints, sdc

### Introduction

Having found multiple, sometimes conflicting or incomplete information on the internet and in some training classes about how to create timing constraints in [SDC format](http://www.synopsys.com/Community/Interoperability/Pages/TapinSDC.aspx) correctly, I'd like to ask the EE community for help with some general clock generating structures I have encountered.

I know that there are differences on how one would *implement* a certain functionality on an ASIC or FPGA (I have worked with both), but I think there should be a general, correct way to constrain the timing of a *given structure*, independent of the underlying technology - please let me know if I'm wrong on that.

There are also some differences between different tools for implementation and timing analysis of different vendors (despite Synopsys offering a SDC parser source code), but I hope that they are mainly a syntax issue which can be looked up in the documentation.

### Question

This is about the following clock multiplexer structure, which is part of the **clkgen** module which is again part of a larger design:
[image: Clock multiplexer schematic]

While the `ext_clk` input is assumed to be generated externally to the design (entering through an input pin), the `clk0` and `clk4` signals are also generated and used by the **clkgen** module (see my related [ripple clock question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/83456/13354) for details) and have associated clock constraints named `baseclk` and `div4clk`, respectively.

The question is how to specify the constraints such that the timing analyser

1. Treats `cpu_clk` as a multiplexed clock which can be either one of the source clocks (`fast_clk` or `slow_clk` or `ext_clk`), taking the delays through the different AND and OR gates into account
2. While at the same time not cutting the paths between the source clocks which are used elsewhere in the design.

While the simplest case of an on-chip clock multiplexer seems to require [just the `set_clock_groups` SDC statement](http://www.altera.com/support/examples/timequest/exm-tq-clock-mux.html):

```
set_clock_groups -logically_exclusive -group {baseclk} -group {div4clk} -group {ext_clk}
```

...in the given structure, this is complicated by the fact that `clk0` (via the `fast_clk` output) and `clk4` (via `slow_clk`) are still used in the design, even if `cpu_clk` is configured to be `ext_clk` when only `use_ext` is asserted.

As described [here](http://quartushelp.altera.com/13.0/master.htm#mergedProjects/tafs/tafs/tcl_pkg_sdc_ver_1.5_cmd_set_clock_groups.htm?GSA_pos=1&WT.oss_r=1&WT.oss=set_clock_groups), the `set_clock_groups` command as above would cause the following:

> This command is equivalent to calling set_false_path from each clock
>   in every group to each clock in every other group and vice versa

...which would be incorrect, since the other clocks are still used elsewhere.

### Additional Information

The `use_clk0`, `use_clk4` and `use_ext` inputs are generated in such a way that only one of them is high at any given time. While this could be used to stop all clocks if all `use_*` inputs are low, the focus of this question is on the clock multiplexing property of this structure.

The **X2** instance (a simple buffer) in the schematic is just a place-holder to highlight the issue of automatic place&route tools being usually free to place buffers anywhere (such as between the `and_cpu_1/z` and `or_cpu1/in2` pins). Ideally, the timing constraints should be unaffected by that.

Comment: Could you try making this more succinct by narrowing it down to a very specific, very narrow question? It is hard for me to understand what is important information, and what you're really after here.

Comment: @trav1s: I restructured the question. Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define divide by 1 clocks on the and_* nets and declare them to be physically exclusive. Cadence RTL compiler handles the situation correctly by generating 3 timing paths for registers clocked by cpu_clk (one path each for one clock). Registers directly driven by clk0, clk4 and clk_ext have their own timing arcs.

```
create_generated_clock -source [get_ports clk0] \
-divide_by 1 -name and_clk0    [get_pins and_cpu_1/Y]

create_generated_clock -source [get_ports clk4] \
-divide_by 1 -name and_clk4    [get_pins and_cpu_2/Y]

create_generated_clock -source [get_ports clk_ext] \
-divide_by 1 -name and_clk_ext [get_pins and_cpu_ext1/Y]

set_clock_groups \
-physically_exclusive \
-group [get_clocks and_clk0] \
-group [get_clocks and_clk4] \
-group [get_clocks and_clk_ext]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I currently can't verify this, but your concept looks quite promising to me. Could you check whether the paths between `cast_clk`, `cpu_clk` and `slow_clk` are still checked (i.e. not an exception due to the exclusive clock groups), while at the same time being constrained by their respective input clocks? Ultimately, I am looking for an authoritative answer to this question.

Comment: @FriendFX I've tested the code in RTL compiler and paths are inferred correctly.

Comment: Just to let you know, I added some information about single-cell clock multiplexers and a solution (at least for some tools).